# What is a good way to attach javascript interactions to the part of webpage which is loaded via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

A common example is the infinite scroll page. When the new content is loaded, all the existing javascript calls should be attached to the new elements. Is there any simple way to achieve this (apart from calling all the js/jquery functions again).

The problem is more severe when there are multiple internal and external .js files which need to be called to enable the interactions.

Comment: `->` http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2):

every time a new element is added ..you can use `on` event to bind events for example take a look at he below code

```
    $( "body" ).on( "click", "p", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

It binds the click event to all `p` which are dynamically added.

[Find more details about .on() here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Actually, it binds the event handler to `body`, but it will handle click events on all `p` elements (which might or might not exist at the time the handler is bound).